# How spine routing (spine js mvc) work?

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc, asp.net-mvc, spine.js

I have tried Spinejs library for a few days, I have the document on Spinejs.com but till now, I still don't know how exactly Spine routing work. From the document, I know how to create a new route and add them to Spine routing. But how it work?
I tried to create an example with 2 controller Task and TaskList extends from Spine.Controller, I also did add 2 routing controllers: "#/task" and "#/tasklist":

```
Spine.route.add("#/task");
Spine.route.add("#/tasklist");
Spine.route.setup();
```

in Task and TaskList controller, I simply alert an message in their constructor.

But when I browse: "http://hellospine.html/#task" -> nothing happen
then "http://hellospine.html/#tasklist" -> nothing happen
I thought that, the route values in url "#task" and "#tasklist" let spine call constructor of appropriate controller, but it's not working.

Do you have any idea ? Should I config anymore to make it run appropriate controller ? I also wanna know work flow of spine routing, please help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

3 things:

1. `Spine.Route.add` is meant to be used out of controllers.
2. route does not need `#`.
3. You have to specify a callback function to execute when the route is reached

so:

```
Spine.Route.add('/hi', function () {
    alert('Hey you!');
});
Spine.Route.setup()
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abernier/xCt9Z/)

But please refer to http://spinejs.com/docs/routing

Cheers.